# CSS flexbox giving unexpected output

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have below markup for testing `flexbox`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .parent{
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
           .parent>div>button{
               display: flex;
           }
           .parent>div:nth-child(2){
               display: flex;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="div1"><button>butt1</button><button>butt7</button></div>
            <div class="div2"><button>butt2</button><button>butt3</button><button>butt4</button>
                <button>butt5</button><button>butt6</button></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Its output is given below:

[image]

What I don't understand is that even if we haven't given any `flex-direction: column` to the `div1` i.e., we haven't written:

```
.parent>div>button{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
  }
```

even then `butt1` and `butt7` are aligned in column. Why they are not aligned in row?? Is it the case that child `div` inherits the value of `flex-direction` of parent? I have read that default value of `flex-direction` is `row`. So, with that logic as well, they should have been aligned row-wise, not column-wise.

Please help me to find the reason of above behaviour.

Thank You.

Comment: This is because you have given the buttons in that div `display:flex`. Remove that and it's not an issue. This seems to apply an effective but not rendered 100% with to the button

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for the response. I haven't used ``flex-direction: column`` on buttons, even then they are aligned column-wise. This is what really confuses me.

Comment: You don't have to apply column to the buttons, just remove the flex from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this:

```css
.parent>div>button{
  display: flex;
}
```

You overwritten default style of button, which is `display: inline-block`. `display: flex` works for children not for element itself, so your buttons behave like normal div (`display: block`). If you want to use flex in your way even if it's inappropriate change it to `display: inline-flex`.

More precise information directly from specification:

> **flex** -
> This value causes an element to generate a flex container box that is block-level when placed in flow layout.
>
> **inline-flex** - This value causes an element to generate a flex container box that is inline-level when placed in flow layout.

@IMPROVEMENT

You have a lot of code that is not needed.

You can achieve same result by:

```css
.parent > div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div>
        <button>butt1</button>
        <button>butt7</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>butt2</button>
        <button>butt3</button>
        <button>butt4</button>
        <button>butt5</button>
        <button>butt6</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am really confused about why this(``.parent>div>button``) thing aligns butt1 and butt7 in column, when I haven't even provided ``flex-direction: column`` property to it.

Comment: @GratisDevs You overwritten default style of `button` which is `display: inline-block`, so you button behaves like normal `div`. I've updated an answer.

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a flex to the `div1` do it like this:

```
.parent>.div1{
    display: flex;
}
```

See here, I've added a background color for you to see what's going on:

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.parent>.div1 {
  background: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.parent>div:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1">
    <button>butt1</button><button>butt7</button>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <button>butt2</button><button>butt3</button><button>butt4</button>
    <button>butt5</button><button>butt6</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this line of CSS is the issue:

```css
.parent>div>button{
  display: flex;
}
```

You are telling css CSS using > that rules will be applied to elements which are direct children of the .parent -> div -> button element.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


.parent>div:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1"><button>butt1</button><button>butt7</button></div>
  <div class="div2"><button>butt2</button><button>butt3</button><button>butt4</button>
    <button>butt5</button><button>butt6</button></div>
</div>
```